# Taking absolute values of a list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, absolute

I have checked similar branches in Stock, however all use some prepared libraries; that's not what i want.

I wanted to create a function that would take a list of numbers, take their absolute values and print the modified list. Here is my code:

```
def abs(array):
    for member in array:
        if member < 0:
            member = member * (-1)
        else:
            member = member

    print(array)
```

But it prints the original list. For example:

```
abs([1, -34, 23, 2342, 52, -3, -12, -123, -23])
```

Gives:

```
[1, -34, 23, 2342, 52, -3, -12, -123, -23]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I am new to Python. Came from Java.

Comment: That would be because `abs` is a preexisting Python function. Try naming your function something else.

Comment: M-Chen-3, very good idea, but I just tried  it ( renamed the function) - yet gives the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is  with the loop you are using , Trying modifying it this way

```py
def abs1(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] < 0:
             array[i] = array[i] * (-1)
    print(array)
```

The reason is the loop you were previously using was just for
accesing list elements but not giving you reference to change anything in list I solved it with using indexes on list.

Comment: I made the necessary edits , and yeah It was just to explain stuff am not returning anything so I can modify it , just printing it

Comment: It worked! Thank you, KnightKnight! Getting accustomed to Python coming from java is a bit pain.

Comment: @ZeynalBagırov Welcome :D, yeah  , I am currently learning Python too , shifted from CPP

Comment: @ZeynalBagırov `array[i] = -array[i]` is a little cleaner, if you want.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thank you! It is!

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
import numpy as np

array= ...

np.abs(np.array(array))
```

`numpy` is very powerful and fast, learn to use it asap.

EDIT since the problem is how to do a function on each element of a list and wrap those results in a list of the same length :

Two solutions come to mind :

- hardcore python style  :

```
[x if x<0 else -x for x in array]
```

the brackets say I want a list, inside I write the function and I say where to find the parameters to my function.

```
[abs(x) for x in array]
[f(x) for x in array] # for any defined f that can handle every element of array
```

- map(lambda x : f(x), array)

you create a mapping on the elements of array. To those elements, you apply lambda. lambda is a way to define a function locally, very locally.

```
list(map(lambda x : abs(x),array))
```

finally you make a list from the mapping, to retrieve the result. If you don't, it will stay as an abstract, the definition of a relation between array and something that is yet to be instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Wanted to learn core principles.

Comment: Ok, try this : [x if x>0 else -x for x in array]

Comment: Another solution is with map lambda : list(map(lambda x : abs(x), array))).

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes with your code:

1. `abs` is a preexisting Python function. Never name your own functions after a preexisting one; it can cause unexpected behavior.
2. You shouldn't modify parameters in a function. Instead, create a new array and return it.

Below is the corrected code:

```py
def list_abs(array):
    new_array = []
    for member in array:
        if member < 0:
            new_array.append(member * (-1))
        else:
            new_array.append(member)
    return new_array

array = [2, 3, 4, -5, -6, 7, -8]
print(list_abs(array))
# Prints [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I guess the problem is the way I used cannot be used to change members of list. It can only be used to access them. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, if you use a for in this way the value won't be assigned into the array.
Try this code.

```
def abs(array):
for i in range(len(array) - 1):
    if array[i] < 0:
        array[i] = array[i] * (-1)

print(array)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is the way I used cannot be used to change members of list. It can only be used to access them. Thank you very much!